# Text animation in karaoke style (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to create a karaoke animation in Hong Kong style but I'm facing some problems

I want to achieve the following effect, where the lyrics of the song highlights according to the music. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obwI5NPyepE)

I have tried to use Gradient, but I am only able to animate the whole text, instead of character by character.

I have all the timesteps for animation of each character already. What tools should I use for the animation?

Comment: Not that i tried it. But look at dotween and textmeshpro bits.

Answer (score 0):

TextMeshPro has built-in markup support for color changing, see [documentation](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#color). This will allow you to do character-by-character:

```
<color=#0000FF>How deep is yo<color=#FFFFFF>ur love
```

Do note that this changes characters discretely (each character is either fully-white or fully-blue), rather than having a single character be filled from white to blue over time.

If you'd prefer the per-character gradient, it's probably easier to have an all-white version and an all-blue version, then use a mask gradient to slowly reveal the blue version.